# Why does this div goes way below 50% of the page instead of going straight to the center?

Tags: html, css

```css
.try {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50%;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="try"></div>
```

Hello sorry for a dumb question, but is it possible to make this div go to the center of the page without using flexbox maybe?

Comment: Why not `flexbox`? It is the best solution to vertically center. Otherwise, try `top: 50%`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set top and transform property in css insted of margin-top.

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```css
.try {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="try"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great way to do that, but it does mean that any content after this will still be pushed as if the element wasn't transformed, but I guess thats not important for a full center. Although I still think a `flexbox` around it and a `margin: auto` is the quickest way and its very well supported now.

Comment: he don't *need* to use `top` .. margin-top will do exactly the same as top since the element is position:relative

Comment: oh i didnt know that. Thanks @TemaniAfif :)

Answer (score -1):

You declare **`margin-top: 50%`** that's why **`div`** goes below **`50%`** down.

```
.try {background-color: aqua;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 25% 0 25% 0;
            position:relative;
        }
<div class="try"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because you set top marging to 50%.set all margins to 50%.